# Google Earth Engine ui.Button and ui.Select fontsize

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am asking regarding the Google Earth Engine Apps. It seems that `ui.Button` and `ui.Select` cannot change their font sizes using `fontSize`  and only the box size changes when applying this argument. I am asking if there is any possibility to do so.

Comment: I've filed a bug to get this fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much @NoelGorelick